# How to get a shell file executed in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

Shell script is a pipeline job  1) where  input  file.json is on remote host .
2) output of the shell script is json and it  should copied to remote host.

curl -u: -X POST -k -H 'Content-Type:text/plain' -i https://<artifactory_host>/artifactory/api/search/aql

Answer (score 0):

Creating a stage within the Jenkins pipeline to execute the script would be a good option to achieve this requirement.
For example:

```
stage('My script execution'){
  steps {
    sh "<script-content>"
        }
}
```

The copy or any SCP operation to forward the JSON files to the output server can be a part of the same script.